# Error Implementando JavaScript para mostrar Modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Buenos Dias a todos, 
Soy nuevo con JavaScript y estoy tratando de implementar un modal de esta pagina "https://codepen.io/nunofidalgo/pen/zrYoVr" ya implemente el CSS pero el JavaScript me esta dando problemas, intente colocando el JS internamente y con un archivo .js pero me da el mismo error "index1.aspx:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Se que es algo tonto pero soy nuevo en esto, gracias 
(Ya agregue los archivos adicionales de referencia que son "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" Y "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" sin embargo me da error en el mismo sitio)

Codigo en JS donde tiene el error

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Codigo Completo

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');

var particleCount = 300;
var particleMax = 1000;
var sky = document.querySelector('.modal');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = sky.clientWidth;
var height = sky.clientHeight;
var i = 0;
var active = false;
var snowflakes = [];
var snowflake;

canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.left = canvas.style.top = '0';




var Snowflake = function () {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.vy = 0;
    this.vx = 0;
    this.r = 0;

    this.reset();
};

Snowflake.prototype.reset = function () {
    this.x = Math.random() * width;
    this.y = Math.random() * -height;
    this.vy = 1 + Math.random() * 3;
    this.vx = 0.5 - Math.random();
    this.r = 1 + Math.random() * 2;
    this.o = 0.5 + Math.random() * 0.5;
};

function generateSnowFlakes() {
    snowflakes = [];
    for (i = 0; i < particleMax; i++) {
        snowflake = new Snowflake();
        snowflake.reset();
        snowflakes.push(snowflake);
    }
}

generateSnowFlakes();

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    if (!active) {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
        snowflake = snowflakes[i];
        snowflake.y += snowflake.vy;
        snowflake.x += snowflake.vx;

        ctx.globalAlpha = snowflake.o;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(snowflake.x, snowflake.y, snowflake.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        if (snowflake.y > height) {
            snowflake.reset();
        }
    }

    requestAnimFrame(update);
}

function onResize() {
    width = sky.clientWidth;
    height = sky.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';

    var wasActive = active;
    active = width > 600;

    if (!wasActive && active) {
        requestAnimFrame(update);
    }
}

// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function (callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
})();

onResize();
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

sky.appendChild(canvas);

var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(window, 'particleCount').min(1).max(particleMax).step(1).name('Particles count').onFinishChange(function () {
    requestAnimFrame(update);
});
```

Llamado desde la pantalla .aspx

```
<script src="Script/query.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muestra todo el código para poder ayudarte mas fácil

Comment: @AnderssonViveros Aqui va el codigo completo del JS

Comment: Edita la pregunta obviamente

Comment: Claro, Ya agregado @AnderssonViveros

Comment: yo diría que si puedes implementar también el html y el css para ejecutarlo en el snippet seria mas sencillo

Comment: Reviso que al llamar `$('#myModal').modal('show');` el selector `#myModal` corresponda al `id` de su ventana modal?

Comment: Asegúrate que el orden de las etiquetas `<script>` es el correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error significa que no ha cargado la librería de jQuery.

Sin ver todo el HTML no puedo estar seguro al 100% de lo que pasa, pero hay dos opciones:

- Te falta añadir el enlace, pero creo que no porque has puesto la URL en la pregunta.
- Tu script está antes de ese enlace, con lo que se ejecuta antes de que jQuery exista en la página.

Comment: Gracias, era la opcion 2